# DB2 SQL Result Set without Duplicates

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to adjust this SQL syntax to only show one row if it has a dash number in the field or field is empty.

```
Select Distinct TRIM(TRANSLATE(itnbr,' ','F')),
Case When t3.dashonly Is NULL Then '' Else t3.dashonly End As dashonly
From amflib1.itmrva t1
Join webprddt1.drawmext17 t2 On t2.afctdwg = t1.uu25
Left Join webprddt1.wqmssoadn t3 On t3.itemno = t1.itnbr
Where t2.recseq = '0060' Order By 1
```

As is the resultset is:

```
 00001           DASHONLY
 --------------- ---------------
 41031052-1      
 41031052-1      -1             
 41031052-10     
 41031052-11     -11            
 41031052-11     
 41031052-12     
 41031052-12     -12            
 41031052-13     
 41031052-14     
 41031052-15     
 41031052-17
```

Desired resultset:

```
 00001           DASHONLY
 --------------- ---------------
 41031052-1      -1             
 41031052-10     
 41031052-11     -11            
 41031052-12     -12            
 41031052-13     
 41031052-14     
 41031052-15     
 41031052-17
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result?

Comment: So, you have some select (it doesn't matter which one exactly) returning the result set above. What's the exact desired result set on this intermediate one?

Comment: See edits on my original post.

Comment: You should use your original SELECT (with some correlation name for the 1-st column) in a subselect with GROUP BY this 1-st column and MAX function on `DASHONLY`. Try in on your own and show your attempt result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I don't have test data to test your query, the query below should work.

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to sort the rows in each subgroup according to a sorting criteria, and then just pick the first one per group.

```
select *
from (
  select
    TRIM(TRANSLATE(itnbr,' ','F')),
    case when t3.dashonly is null then '' else t3.dashonly end As dashonly,
    row_number() over(partition by TRIM(TRANSLATE(itnbr,' ','F'))
      order by case when t3.dashonly is null then 0 else 1 end) as rn
  from amflib1.itmrva t1
  join webprddt1.drawmext17 t2 on t2.afctdwg = t1.uu25
  left join webprddt1.wqmssoadn t3 on t3.itemno = t1.itnbr
  where t2.recseq = '0060'
) x 
where rn = 1
order by 1
```